# Flex 4.5 PropertyGrid Editor

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am interested in a PropertyGrid Editor for Flex. Basically, it would be something like this: http://www.cnblogs.com/janyou/archive/2009/07/28/1532919.html but that I can get the source of!

If no component like that exists, I'd need assistance on creating one.

Basically what I need is:

- Grabbing a list of properties from a specified object (which can be changed in runtime) - but just the properties I mark
- This list of properties would be shown in a List or a DataGrid control in Flex
- You can edit those properties with the correspondant control (textinput for string, numericstepper for Number, checkbox for boolean, colorchoose for color [specified which ones are color], etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what that link actually does.  But, it includes a lot of Flex Source code.  What is a PropertyGrid editor?

Comment: Actually it just shows the usage of the propertygrid, but doesn't show the code of it. Basically a propertygrid editor would be like the demo swf below (like Visual C# property grid and C# propertygrid component, screenshot: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/Images/FAQs/AddControlAsProperty/PropertyGrid.gif)

Comment: Okay...  I don't understand what problems you're having creating one.  Can you just use a Panel with a Form in it?  What are you expecting a component to offer you?

Comment: as you can see with the first link, it dinamically grabs the properties and automatically creates the needed controls to edit them, by using the custom metatags offered.

Comment: The first link did not communicate that to me; as it has no explanation of what each step means.  I understand what you want now, though.  I don't know of a component to do that.

Comment: Edited the question. Basically, I also would need assistance in creating one if nothing exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this would be to use a for..in loop and loop through all of the properties of an object. Then use ObjectUtil.hasMetadata() on each property and loop through all possible metadata tags to organize them into predetermined categories.

eg.

```
var gridData:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();
for(var prop:String in obj)
{
    var gridItem:Object = new Object();
    gridItem.property = prop;
    gridItem.value = obj[prop];
    for each(var tag:String in metaDataTags)
    {
        if(ObjectUtil.hasMetadata(obj,prop,tag)
        {
            gridItem.category = tag;
            break;
        }
    }
    gridData.addItem(gridItem);
}
```

If you need to get fancy with all the enums and custom categories like the example in your question, you will have to use flash.utils.describeType. This function returns an XML with all property and metadata information. Just parse this XML and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! This was really useful! I will post my class when it's done :D